# Why does TableView become unresponsive?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a tabbed page that has several pages, all of them contain ListViews or TableViews. Sometimes, when I navigate here and there, the lists and the tables become unclickable, until I click randomly several times. Has anyone experienced similar problems? What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Here's the related [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44005/listview-is-not-working-properly-when-used-inside-a-tabbedpage) (my post is the last).

I experienced the same problem with ListViews, until I added this code which helped:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(MyApp.Droid.ListtViewCustomRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class ListtViewCustomRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
            this.Control.SetSelection(0);
        }

        public ListtViewCustomRenderer()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

It's a shoot in the dark, but looks like you are not disposing the pages and their resources when disappearing.

Remember to free all resources from a page when it's done, especially images.

Comment: How should I do that? Could you give me a link yo some resource or something

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#idisposable

Comment: If you could share the code, I may be able to help more. But I understand that sometimes isn't possible.

Comment: Hm... Should I do all that when navigating to the different page in TabbedPage?

Comment: As I told you, it's a shoot in the dark, a guess due my lack of more knowledge on what you are doing or not. Profiler can help you here. But yeah, I would try to dispose as much as I can and see how it goes.